# Multiplying two data frames in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames as shown below df1 and df2. I want to create a third dataframe i.e. df as shown below. What would be the appropriate way?

```
df1={'id':['a','b','c'],
   'val':[1,2,3]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df)
df1
 id  val
0  a    1
1  b    2
2  c    3


df2={'yr':['2010','2011','2012'],
   'val':[4,5,6]}

df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2
    yr  val
0  2010    4
1  2011    5
2  2012    6

df={'id':['a','b','c'],
   'val':[1,2,3],
    '2010':[4,8,12],
    '2011':[5,10,15],
    '2012':[6,12,18]}


df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df

  id  val  2010  2011  2012
0  a    1     4     5     6
1  b    2     8    10    12
2  c    3    12    15    18
```

I can basically convert df1 and df2 as 1 by n matrices and get n by n result and assign it back to the df1. But is there any easy pandas way?

Comment: There are some missing values from your df2. Maybe you mean: [[4,8,12], [5,10,15], [6,12,18]]?

Comment: sorry why [4,8,2] and not [4,8,12] ?

Comment: I made a typo there ...

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos I want to multiply 'val' col in df2 with each row of val col in df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
df2 = df2.T
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(df1['val'],df2.iloc[1:]))
df = pd.concat([df1, new_df], axis=1)
df.columns = ['id', 'val', '2010', '2011', '2012']
df
```

The output I get:

```
    id  val 2010    2011    2012
0   a   1      4       5       6
1   b   2      8      10      12
2   c   3     12      15      18
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

We can do it in one line like this:

```
df1.join(df1.val.apply(lambda x: x * df2.set_index('yr').val))
```

or like this:

```
df1.join(df1.set_index('id') @ df2.set_index('yr').T, on='id')
```

Done.

### The long story

Let's see what's going on here.

To find the output of multiplication of each `df1.val` by values in `df2.val` we use `apply`:

```
df1['val'].apply(lambda x: x * df2.val)
```

The function inside will obtain `df1.val`s one by one and multiply each by `df2.val` element-wise (see [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for details if needed). As far as `df2.val` is a pandas sequence, [the output is a data frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with indexes `df1.val.index` and columns  `df2.val.index`. By `df2.set_index('yr')` we force years to be indexes before multiplication so they will become column names in the output.

`DataFrame.join` is [joining frames index-on-index by default](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?pandas.DataFrame.join). So due to identical indexes of `df1` and the multiplication output, we can apply `df1.join( <the output of multiplication> )` as is.

At the end we get the desired matrix with indexes `df1.index` and columns `id, val, *df2['yr']`.

The second variant with `@` operator is actually the same. The main difference is that we multiply 2-dimentional frames instead of series. These are the vertical and horizontal vectors, respectively. So the [matrix multiplication](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) will produce a frame with indexes `df1.id` and columns `df2.yr` and element-wise multiplication as values. At the end we connect `df1` with the output on identical `id` column and index respectively.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't intended to solve the immediate problem, it is intended to also solve problems future readers may be facing. Say a future reader is new to the language, it would be useful if the answer contained information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. But I suppose you want to do something like that:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```